# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException for date JSON serializer converts a list into string

Tags: java, json, spring, getjson

When i try to convert my list JSON serializer coverts a list into string
with following code

```
JSON jsonString = JSONSerializer.toJSON(myList);
```

It give following exception

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException  
java.sql.Date.getHours(Date.java:143)
```

Comment: Can you give details on what's in the list.

Comment: In list i have data fetched for store procedure it is containing one column which contain sql date .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=83378

Solution is to use java.sql.Time instead of java.sql.Date

Comment: I am not using java.sql.Date list is coming from data base it is result set of store procedure.

Comment: but in sp date is used i have to use date.